# two's complement representation of a negative number, on a given number of (hexa) digits

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, how could I get a clean two's complement hexa representation of a negative number, on a given number of (hexa) digits ?

I already know that :

```
irb(main):003:0> a=-7
=> -7
irb(main):005:0> str = "0x" << sprintf("%X",x)
=> "0x..F9"
```

Then I further need to

1. suppress ".."
2. propagate "F" when necessary

Is there any idiom to dot that properly ?

JCLL

Comment: This question is actually nonsense.

Comment: pguardiario, could you explain why you consider that nonsens ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about doing the subtraction yourself when the number is negative:

```
sprintf("%#X",16**digits-7)
```